# Are "more keenly than" and "more keenly that" equivalent and correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, phrase-choice

I accidentally came across these two phrases, and wondered if they were both correct. I particularly **“struggled”** with “more keenly that”… It didn’t feel right to me.

What do you think? What is the difference?

Then, I did some research and found two example sentences for both.

▪️... few communities are watching the unfolding drama more keenly that in Berwick, a town of 12,000 people just four kilometres from the border ...
▪️ This compulsion to record and account is felt nowhere more keenly that in the State Archives of Palermo, housed in a building usually closed ...

Few questions in historical geography have been more keenly discussed than that of the first discovery of Guinea by the navigators of modern Europe.
 Nowhere was the result felt more keenly than in Mexico.

Thank you for your feedback. I look forward to reading your comments,

Yours faithfully,

Answer (score 2):

*Than* and *that* are completely different words. In your first two examples, *that* is clearly a typo for *than* - the phrase *more keenly than* compares the degree of 'keen-ness' shown by two people or groups. There us no such expression as *more [adverb] that*.

Comment: Thank you very much Kate for making that clear to me. I came across those typos and it brought confusion and uncertainty in my mind. Thanks again,